# How can I make this overloaded param method work?

Tags: c#, overloading, parameters

I have the following code:

```
public static void AssertTdsExist(this RemoteWebDriver driver, string id, params string[] tds)
{
    ...
}

public static void AssertTdsExist(this RemoteWebDriver driver, params string[] tds)
{
    ...
}
```

Now when I do `Driver.AssertTdsExist("pol_imp");` the first method is invoked. But i want to invoke the second method.

How should I change this code to make it work?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479364/c-sharp-params-keyword-with-two-parameters-of-the-same-type

Comment: Do not not get the error "No overload for method 'AssertdsExists' takes 1 arguments ?

Comment: @StarterPack No it compiles nice and tidy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest you can do is to not change anything at all, and simply call your method with named parameters, so that there is no ambiguity :

```
    // assuming you retrieve your params from somewhere
    var tdsArray = new string[] {"pol_imp"};
    var myDriver = GetDriver();
    var myId = GetId();

    myDriver.AssertTdsExist(tds: tdsArray);
    // or this, to call the other method
    myDriver.AssertTdsExist(tds: tdsArray, id: myId);
```

Comment: Yes this is a nice suggestion! Although it doesn't seem necessary to make a string array, `myDriver.AssertTdsExist(tds: "pol_imp")` works. Although I removed my overload and use null for id instead. This gets too error prone.

Answer (score 2):

You can supply the argument in a string array:

```
Driver.AssertTdsExist(new string[] { "pol_imp" });
```

This only matches the second method.

Answer (score 1):

You can change string Id to StringBuilder so it will be differ from each other... like this

> public static void AssertTdsExist(this RemoteWebDriver driver, StringBuilder id, params string[] tds)
>   {
>       ...
>   }
>
> public static void AssertTdsExist(this RemoteWebDriver driver, params string[] tds)
>   {
>       ...
>   }